# Loop the formula array into Range (B24:N24) after that fill down to (B33:N33)?

Tags: excel, vba

The issue is at `destRange.Columns(i).Formula = formulaArray(i)`
below is my coding:

```vb
Sub Formula()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim formulaArray(1 to 10) As String
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim destRange As Range


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")

ws.Activate

formulaArray(1) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!G3, ""),"")"
formulaArray(2) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!H4, ""), "")"
formulaArray(3) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!E5, ""), "")"
formulaArray(4) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!F6, ""), "")"
formulaArray(5) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!I7, ""), "")"
formulaArray(6) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!J8, ""), "")"
formulaArray(7) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!L9, ""), "")"
formulaArray(8) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!M10, ""), "")"
formulaArray(9) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!N11, ""), "")"
formulaArray(10) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!O12, ""), "")"

Set destRange = ws.Range("B24:N24")
    
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 to 10
        destRange.Columns(i).Formula = formulaArray(i)
    Next i

destRange.FillDown


End Sub
```

I want to fill in the formula to rage ("B24:N24") and fill down to ("B33:N33")

Comment: In the formula for formulaArray(4), there's a missing comma before the 0 in the MATCH function. formulaArray(4) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!F6, ""), "")"

Answer (score 0):

The `FillDown` method will only fill down the first cell of `destRange`. You need to specify the range to fill down to.

Code below should now correctly fill in the formulas in the range `B24:N24` and then fill them down to `B33:N33`.

Revised code:

```vb
Sub Formula()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim formulaArray(1 To 10) As String
Dim destRange As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")

ws.Activate

formulaArray(1) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!G3, """"), """")"
formulaArray(2) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!H4, """"), """")"
formulaArray(3) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!E5, """"), """")"
formulaArray(4) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!F6, """"), """")"
formulaArray(5) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!I7, """"), """")"
formulaArray(6) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!J8, """"), """")"
formulaArray(7) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!L9, """"), """")"
formulaArray(8) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!M10, """"), """")"
formulaArray(9) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!N11, """"), """")"
formulaArray(10) = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Raw Data'!$D3, MATCH(TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!$D3, 0)) = TODAY(), 'Raw Data'!O12, """"), """")"

Set destRange = ws.Range("B24:N24")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
    destRange.Columns(i).Formula = formulaArray(i)
Next i

' Specify the range to fill down to
ws.Range("B24:N33").FillDown

End Sub
```